# How to tell if something is a container?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, containers, sfinae

I want to determine if something is a container. Right now I'm testing it on containers that are formatted to have a type and allocator. My ultimate goal is to learn how to write a container template that, when containing layers of itself can allow direct iteration on its innermost elements. E.g. if there was a container of 3 containers each containing 3 more containers, each containing 3 elements, I want to be able to iterate through all 27 elements in one range based for loop. Distinguishing whether something is a container that directly contains elements or contains containers of elements (or containers of containers...of containers of elements) using SFINAE to check whether the element has an iterator seems like a logical first step towards determining whether the `begin()` function should return the iterator to the element or the result of said element's `begin()` function. If I can get my first step to work, I'd like to include that logic into writing my container, but I can't get it to compile:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T,
    template <typename E, typename Allocator = std::allocator<E>> class Container
>
void is_cont(typename Container<T>::iterator it)
{
    std::cout << "is iterator\n";
}

template <typename T,
    template <typename E, typename Allocator = std::allocator<E>> class Container
>
void is_cont(Container<T>& cont)
{
    std::cout << "is container\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{ 2, 4, 6 };
    is_cont(vec);               // Output: "is container"
    //is_cont(vec.begin());     // COMPILER ERROR
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Given the iterator `vec.begin()` (which is quite likely just to be an `int*`), there's no way the compiler can instantiate every possible Container class to see if that iterator happens to be of the type `Container<T>::iterator`. And even if it could, it would probably be ambiguous. You would have to specify the template parameters for the function explicitly.

Comment: @Kundor If `vec.begin()` is an `int*`, wouldn’t there still be a `std::vector<int>::iterator`, with the difference being that it’s a `typedef` for `int*`? It seems replacing the line `std::vector<int> vec{ 2, 4, 6 };` with `std::vector<Bar> vec(3, Bar{});` where `Bar` is an empty dummy `struct` gives the same error.

Comment: Yes. So? Given a function call `is_cont(int*)`, the compiler is supposed to deduce the template parameters. So you're asking it to work backwards from `int*` to find a type with a member typedef `iterator` which is `int*`. Surely you can see this cannot work (for one thing, since these are template classes, there are literally infinite possibilities it would have to examine).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your definition of whether something is or is not a container appears to be based solely on whether it has an `iterator` inner class.

That's as good of a heuristic as any, I suppose, but let's go with that.

It most instances, `SFINAE` is much simpler if it's done with classes, instead of trying to implement `SFINAE` with a function, like your `is_container()`. Making your `is_container()` into a class results in a following, textbook `SFINAE` solution:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename ...>
using void_t=void;

template<typename T, class=void> struct is_container : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_container<T, void_t<typename T::iterator>> : std::true_type {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_container<int>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_container<std::vector<int>>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, a related question would be whether there's a better way to check if something is a container, or not. Whichever heuristic you choose, it's trivial to adjust a class-based test, instead of a function-based. For example, if you want to consider whether something is a container if it has both `iterator` and `const_iterator` inner classes, just need to change one line:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_container<T, void_t<typename T::iterator,
                              typename T::const_iterator>> : std::true_type {};
```